# ListBox Multiple Select Method

Tags: c#, ribbon

I have a listbox and a listview. When I select multiple items on Listbox and click to add then it adds first selected item to the listview. I can not overcome to this problem. Meanwhile, Listbox selection mode is  extended.

```
void reinit()
{
    if (_adrlinks == null)
        return;
    object li = listAdr.SelectedItem;
    listAdr.Items.Clear();
    foreach (LnkAdresse ele in _adrlinks) {
        if (((Filter == eFilter.all) || (Filter == eFilter.basic && ele.RType <= 1) ||
             (Filter == eFilter.synteilnehmer && ele.RType == 8) ||
             (Filter == eFilter.deliveryteam && ele.RType >= 16 && ele.RType <= 31) ||
             (Filter == eFilter.explorationteam && ele.RType >= 32 && ele.RType <= 63)
            ) && (int)ele.mut >= 0)
        {
            listAdr.Items.Add(ele);  //listAdr is my listview
            if (ele == li)
                listAdr.SelectedItem = li;
        }
    }
    //NotifyContent("changeDoc", "", "");
}
```

Comment: You should give better names to your variables. Instead of having comments like "listAdr is my listview", call it `addressListView` instead. Where is your ListBox?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely unclear, to get mutiple selected items from the listbox, you use the SelectedItems property, however if you do, I'm having to make a huge guess at what you want to do with it.

Pehaps

```
void reinit()
{
  if (_adrlinks == null) return;
  listAdr.Items.Clear();
  foreach(var li in ListAdr.SelectedItems)
  {
    foreach (LnkAdresse ele in _adrlinks)
    {
      if (((Filter == eFilter.all) || (Filter == eFilter.basic && ele.RType <= 1) || (Filter == eFilter.synteilnehmer && ele.RType == 8)
                || (Filter == eFilter.deliveryteam && ele.RType >= 16 && ele.RType <= 31) || (Filter == eFilter.explorationteam && ele.RType >= 32 && ele.RType <= 63))
                && (int)ele.mut >= 0)
      {
        listAdr.Items.Add(ele);  //listAdr is my listview
        // commented out as it won't ever be true in a multiselect scenario
        // and wouldn't make any sense if it did 
        //if (ele == li) listAdr.SelectedItem = li;
      }
    }
  }
  //NotifyContent("changeDoc", "", "");
}
```

maybe ???

Comment: you are right. It is not so clear. I am a new developer. This part of edition has been given to me as my first work. That's why I could not write clearly.

Answer (score 1):

While not answering your question directly, I suggest you to make your code more readable and maintainable. Maybe your problem will disappear then?

One suggestion: Create a filter method like this

```
private bool TakeLinkAddress(eFilter filter, LnkAdresse linkAddress)
{
    if ((int)linkAddress.mut < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int rType = linkAddress.RType;
    switch (filter) {
        case eFilter.all:
            return true;
        case eFilter.basic:
            return rType <= 1;
        case eFilter.synteilnehmer:
            return rType == 8;
        case eFilter.deliveryteam:
            return rType >= 16 && rType <= 31;
        case eFilter.explorationteam:
            return rType >= 32 && rType <= 63;
        case else:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Also give better names to your variables. Now your loop looks much nicer:

```
foreach (LnkAdresse linkAddress in _adrlinks) {
    if (TakeLinkAddress(filter, linkAddress)) {
        linkAddressListView.Items.Add(linkAddress);
        if (linkAddress == selectedLinkAddress) {
            linkAddressListView.SelectedItem = selectedLinkAddress;
        }
    }
}
```